# Display an html iframe object inside an HTA application that uses javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows, exe, hta

I seek to run the following iframe object inside an HTA application and would like to later convert this to an exe file.

```
<iframe height="620" class="wizard-frame" style="max-width: 100% !important; border: 1px solid #dadada; overflow-y: hidden;" scrolling="no" src="https://www.rnv-online.de/timetable/?design=3&width=390&destination=" width="390"></iframe>
```

The appearance of the applicaiton should look as displayed here:
https://www.rnv-online.de/fahrtinfo/fahrplaene/fahrplanauskunfts-widget/

Here is the HTML Code I have come up with:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<html>
<body>
<iframe 
       height="620" 
       class="wizard-frame" 
       style="max-width: 100% !important; border: 1px solid #dadada; overflow-y: hidden;" scrolling="no" src="https://www.rnv-online.de/timetable/?design=3&width=390&destination=" width="390"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the HTA file, I receive an error, which I can skip and get the asked widget. However, it is not interactive and I assume Javascript is an issue here. How can I get to work properly?

Comment: Remember that MSHTA uses the old IE  engine which used JScript (EMCAScript v3) not JavaScript in it’s modern form.

Comment: To interact with the iframe, you need to add `application="true"` attribute to the iframe tag.

Answer (score 0):

The page in the script does not work in IE 11 (e.g. calendar and clock do not work at all). If the page doesn't work in IE 11, it won't work in an HTA iframe either.

If you can find a page that actually works with IE 11, then the following information may be of use...

Even with the x-ua-compatible line in the HTA, the external site will get the mshta.exe default user agent header which is MSIE 7.0 by default. To ensure the external site gets an IE 11 header, apply this registry setting:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"mshta.exe"=dword:00002af8
```

That will change the mshta.exe default mode from IE=7 to IE=11.

While this answer may appear to be a duplicate of other answers that refer to x-ua-compatible and the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry value, I could not find any answers that made it clear that the x-ua-compatible setting does not carry over to the iframe. Here's a sample HTA script that demonstrates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
</head>
<body>
<script>
window.resizeTo(850,650);
alert(document.documentMode + "\n\n" + window.navigator.userAgent);
</script>
<iframe width=800 height=550 src="https://gs.statcounter.com/detect"</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```